# Upload Image causing issue with unobtrusive javascript validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, input, unobtrusive-validation

In MVC 4 view we have one input type file as image control.

```
<input type="file" id="imageUpload"  name = "imagetoupload"  onchange="readURL(this);" accept="*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.jpeg"/>
```

When we submit the form without selecting image, all validations (both JQuery as well as model) triggered successfully.

However when we upload an image and submit the form no validations are fired. We tried   explicitly exclude the validations for the image upload by using the following code on submit click, without any luck.

```
$("#frmRegister").validate({
        ignore:"input[type='file']"
        });
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a custom script for that error

```
function readURL(input) {

        var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'];
        if ($.inArray($(input).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
            alert('@resourceFactory.GetLocalizedValue(PhraseConstants.InvalidFileType)');
            location.reload();
            return false;
        } 

        if (input.files)
        {
            if (input.files[0] && input.files[0].size <= GetFileSize()) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#fileToUpload')
                            .attr('src', e.target.result)
                            .width(90)
                            .height(90);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                alert('@resourceFactory.GetLocalizedValue(ImageSizeExceed)');
            }
        }
    }
```